# What tool can I use to convert C# 3 to VB.Net 9 .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

What tool can I use to convert C# 3 to VB.Net 9 .Net 3.5?

Comment: Note that there's no such thing as "C# 3.5" or "VB.NET 3.5". I suspect you mean "C# 3" and "VB 9".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ; [Scott Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx)

[Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) - Website that converts C# to VB and VB to C#.

[CarlosAg's CodeTranslator](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) - One of the first, and many say, the best. An AJAXy Code Converter that'll do to and from C# and VB.NET.

[DeveloperFusion Code Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) - This online utility will also convert .NET 3.5 Syntax and LINQ between C# and VB.

Answer (score 3):

[Convert C# to VB.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Answer (score 2):

You could compile it and then use Reflector to decompile into VB

Comment: always a nice solution when you don't have the source

Answer (score 2):

you can try this http://converter.telerik.com/